# In Scala, how do i tell an abstract base class that type parameter T supports implicit conversion from Int (or Float, or...)?

Tags: scala, traits, type-parameter, implicits

I'm having difficulty transitioning from the world of C++/Templates to scala.  I'm used to being able to use any operation on a template parameter T that I want, as long as anything I use to instantiate T with supports those operations (compile-time Duck typing, basically).  I cannot find the corresponding idiom in Scala that will allow me to define an abstract class with a single type parameter, and which expects a certain interface for type T.

What I have almost works, but I cannot figure out how to tell the abstract class (Texture[T <: Summable[T]]) that T supports conversion/construction from an Int. How can I add the implicit conversion to the trait Summable so that Texture knows T supports the conversion?

```
trait Summable[T] { 
   def += (v : T) : Unit
   def -= (v : T) : Unit   
}

object Int4 { implicit def int2Int4(i : Int) = new Int4(i, i, i, i) }

class Int4 (var x : Int, var y : Int, var z : Int, var w : Int) extends Summable[Int4] {
   def this (v : Int) = this(v, v, v, v)
   def += (v : Int4) : Unit = { x += v.x; y += v.y; z += v.z; w += v.w }
   def -= (v : Int4) : Unit = { x -= v.x; y -= v.y; z -= v.z; w -= v.w } 
}

abstract class Texture[Texel <: Summable[Texel]] {
   var counter : Texel
   def accumulate(v : Texel) : Unit = { counter += v }
   def decrement() : Unit = { counter -= 1 } //< COMPILE ERROR HERE, fails to find implicit
}

class Int4Target extends Texture[Int4] {
   var counter : Int4 = new Int4(0, 1, 2, 3)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define an implicit constructor parameter like this

```
abstract class Texture[Texel <: Summable[Texel]](implicit int2Texel: Int => Texel) {
//...
```

This essentially tells the compiler that in order to construct an instance of `Texture`, there must be an implicit conversion function available from `Int` to `Texel`.  Assuming you have such a function defined somewhere in scope (which you do), you should no longer get a compile error.

Edit2: Ok I originally misread your code, you actually only need one implicit parameter from `Int => Texel`.  Your code compiles for me with the above modification.

Edit: You'll actually need 2 conversion functions, one from `Texel => Int` and another from `Int => Texel` in order to properly reassign the var

Answer (score 3):

A fundamental difference between C++ templates and anything in Scala is that C++ templates are compiled for each use -- that is, if you use a template with `int` and with `double`, then two different classes are compiled, and they are only compiled when some code actually makes use of it.

Scala, on the other hand, has separate compilation. Not as good as Java's, given JVM limitations, but still following the basic principle. So, if something has a type parameter, it's still compiled at declaration, and only one such class ever exists. That compiled code has to support all possible parameters than it can be called with, which makes for rather different restrictions than templates.

On the matter of traits and implicit conversions, traits do not support parameters, and implicit conversions (view bounds) are parameters. Instead, use a class.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in scala to require an implicit conversion to exist for a type
parameter of a trait. There is a good reason for this. Suppose we defined a
trait like:

```
trait ATrait[T <% Int] {
    def method(v: T) { println(v: Int) }
}
```

And then made instances of it in two places:

```
package place1 {
    implicit def strToInt(s: String) = 5
    val inst = new ATrait[String]
}

package place2 {
    implicit def strToInt(s: String) = 6
    val inst = new ATrait[String]
}
```

And then used these instances like:

```
val a = if (someTest) place1 else place2
a.method("Hello")
```

Should this print `5` or `6`? That is, which implicit conversion should it use?
Implicits have to be found at compile time, but you don't know which implicit
conversion was present for the creation of the object.

In other words, implicits are provided by the scope in which they are used, not
by the objects they are used on; the latter would be impossible.

So, about your problem. Instead of using an implicit, you could use an ordinary
member:

```
trait Summable[T] { 
   def -= (v: T): Unit
   def -= (v: Int) { this -= (encode(v)) }

   def encode(i: Int): T
}

class Int4 (var x: Int, var y: Int, var z: Int, var w: Int) extends Summable[Int4] {
   def -= (v : Int4) : Unit = { x -= v.x; y -= v.y; z -= v.z; w -= v.w } 

   def encode(i: Int) = Int4.int2Int4(i)
}
```

Now the `decrement` method compiles correctly.

Another way of saying this is, don't think of implicits as properties belonging
to a type (ie, "can be implicitly converted from an Int" isn't a property of
Int4). They are values, which can be identified using types.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't follow your objection to implicits on traits. Implicits on traits are not possible because traits do not support construtors. Classes can and often do have implicits, including ones such as requested here -- so why can classes have it but not traits (besides lacking constructors)?

Comment: @Daniel exactly that. Because the class has a constructor the implicit becomes a parameter, and so becomes a member. With a trait all members are declared explicitly. Basically my point is that without a member you can't carry the implicit value around, so it can't appear in the signature as [T <% S]. And even a class with an implicit parameter, people using an instance of the class won't have it automatically in scope.